# react native trigger actions from incoming SMS

Tags: react-native

Ive seen some apps that manage to automatically populate a textInput (and trigger button click) from an incoming SMS.  Ive seen it used very effectively when user registers with phone number and a confirmation code is sent to phone via SMS.....code is then automatically populated into textInput and button is clicked.
Im assuming theres some type of event listener for incoming SMS.
Anyone know if theres a react native library that can enable you to listen to incoming SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like the next one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-sms-listener

I never used it but found it.

Comment: Great find - if anyone knows the ios sister that would be awesome